# Is there a way to enable the metadata API for trial accounts?

Tags: api, metadata-api

According [documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/platform/force-trial-FAQ.jsp) , trial accounts have API access, but I'm getting this error:

> API_DISABLED_FOR_ORG: API is not enabled for this Organization or
>   Partner

When trying to use the metadata API using credentials of a trial account.

Also within the administration console, I can't found any option to enable it (Setup -> Develop -> API)

Is there a way to enable the metadata API for trial accounts?

Answer (score 4):

Only trial accounts that would have API access normally have the API. For example, a group edition trial will not have the API, but an enterprise edition trial will.

Assuming you're on a trial which should have API access, You can contact technical support, and they should oblige you. If you signed up for one which does not, but want access anyways, you can still ask, as they'll usually accommodate short term API access. Failing that, talk to your trial account executive, and they will most likely help you out.

Finally, if you're on the wrong trial, sign up for a new one with the right edition, or ask your account executive to sign one up for you.

Comment: Thank you, but, there is no option to choose the Edition in the trial subscription form. So, how can I know what is my edition? Also, how can I contact to my account executive?

Comment: [Enterprise Edition Free 30-Day Trial](https://www.salesforce.com/form/signup/freetrial-sales-ee.jsp) to get a new trial: there are different forms for each edition, and if you fill out the wrong one, you'll get a lesser edition. Your account executive should have emailed or called you within a couple of days of setting up the current trial, assuming you provided the correct phone number and/or email address.